# custom alphabetic sort in perl hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash the structure is like :

```
my %my_hash=(
 'gee1' =>  {
                   'gene' => '20',
                   'mRNA' => '9',
                   'CDS' => '10',
                    'exon' => '10',
                    'product' => '10',
               },
'gee2'   =>  {
                     'gene' => 'aa',
                   'mRNA' => '9',
                   'CDS' => '1aa',
                    'exon' => '1aa',
                    'product' => 'ab',

               },
'gee4'   =>  {
                     'gene' => 'aa',
                   'rRNA' => '9',
                    'product' => 'ab',
                    'locus' => 'abc'

               },
'gee11'   =>  {
                     'gene' => 'aa',
                   'rRNA' => '9',
                    'product' => 'ab',
                    'locus' => 'abc'

               });
```

when I am trying to print the hash in the above order, using the bellow code :

```
for my $id ( sort { my ($anum) = ($a =~ /\w(\d+)$/);  my ($bnum) = ($b =~ /\w(\d+)$/);  $anum <=> $bnum} keys %my_hash)
{
    print "$id\n";
    for my $id1 (keys %{$my_hash{$id}})
    {
            print "\t$id1\n";
    }
}
```

the out put is like this :

```
gee1
    product
    exon
    gene
    mRNA
    CDS
gee2
    product
    exon
    CDS
    mRNA
    gene
gee4
    product
    locus
    gene
    rRNA
gee11
    rRNA
    gene
    product
    locus
```

you can see that

```
product
exon
gene
mRNA
CDS
```

the above part is not in ordered.
is their any way to sort the above part?

order is like:
    **gene,mRNA,rRNA,CDS,exon,product,locus**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a hash by which you can sort the keys:

```
my %keys_sort;
my $c = 0;
$keys_sort{$_} = $c++ for qw( gene mRNA rRNA CDS exon product locus );
```

and use it to sort them:

```
for my $id1 (sort { $keys_sort{$a} <=> $keys_sort{$b} }
             keys %{ $my_hash{$id} }
) {
```

Or, use the list directly, but `grep` only the relevant keys:

```
for my $id1 (grep exists $my_hash{$id}{$_},
             qw( gene mRNA rRNA CDS exon product locus )
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the order you want to see the sub keys as:

```
sub by_int_suffix{
  my ($anum) = ($a =~ /\w(\d+)$/);
  my ($bnum) = ($b =~ /\w(\d+)$/);
  $anum <=> $bnum;
}

my @sub_key_order = qw(gene mRNA rRNA CDS exon product locus);
my @key_order = sort by_int_suffix keys %my_hash;
for my $id ( @key_order ){
    print "$id\n";
    for my $id1 (@sub_key_order){
            next unless exists $my_hash{$id}->{$id1};
            print "\t$id1\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried with the your code ..the output is not in my desired order .the present order is :  CDS
 exon
 gene
 mRNA
 product

Comment: The inner loop is unsorted in the original example, and sorted alphabetically in this one. Neither are the desired result - this isn't so much a custom sort, as a fixed return order.

Comment: I missed that subtlety in your original question.  If you know the order you want the sub keys listed in then just define that head of time!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest for a sort routine of that length, you stop trying to embed as an anonymous sub.

Sort will take a reference to a subroutine. This subroutine may take any generic `$a` and `$b` and return -1, 0 or 1. (e.g. as `cmp` or `<=>` do) based on absolutely any criteria you like.

What is important to note here - hashes are explicitly unordered. Indeed, they are often deliberately random-ordered behind the scenes. So you need to *also* sort your 'inner' hash.

So with that in mind, I would suggest something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %my_hash = (
    'gee1' => {
        'gene'    => '20',
        'mRNA'    => '9',
        'CDS'     => '10',
        'exon'    => '10',
        'product' => '10',
    },
    'gee2' => {
        'gene'    => 'aa',
        'mRNA'    => '9',
        'CDS'     => '1aa',
        'exon'    => '1aa',
        'product' => 'ab',

    },
    'gee4' => {
        'gene'    => 'aa',
        'rRNA'    => '9',
        'product' => 'ab',
        'locus'   => 'abc'

    },
    'gee11' => {
        'gene'    => 'aa',
        'rRNA'    => '9',
        'product' => 'ab',
        'locus'   => 'abc'

    }
);

sub sort_key_number {
    my ($anum) = ( $a =~ /(\d+)$/ );
    my ($bnum) = ( $b =~ /(\d+)$/ );

    #print "$anum, $bnum\n";
    return $anum <=> $bnum;
}

my @subkeys = qw ( gene mRNA rRNA CDS exon product locus );

foreach my $key ( sort {sort_key_number} keys %my_hash ) {
    print "\n", $key, ":\n";
    foreach my $subkey (@subkeys) {
        print "\t", $subkey, " = ", $my_hash{$key}{$subkey} || '', "\n";
    }
}
```

You've sorted your outer hash by 'key number'. And your inner hash, you work through in a specific order each time (defined by `@subkeys`).

If you want a bit of a trick, that last `foreach` loop you could do with a slice:

```
print join ( "\n\t", @{$my_hash{$key}}{@subkeys} );
```

But I decided not to in the interests of clarity.

Comment: My guess would be that the subhash values are important, but the OP doesn't actually *say so*! By the way, you mean a *slice*: `splice` is something different, and your single `print` isn't equivalent to the `for` loop as it doesn't print the `$subkey, " = "` part and doesn't default non-existent values to the empty string

Comment: When I tested it that join did print 'null' lines for the empty values. Amended on the splice.

Comment: Yes, as you know Perl itself will stringify `undef` to the null string, but with an associated warning unless you have `no warnings 'uninitialized'` in effect. I'm just saying that your `join` doesn't explicitly default false hash values to a null string as your principle code does

Comment: I had expected warnings; didn't get any. Not sure if that's because I'm missing something daft though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unusual to show only the *keys* of the second-level hashes, but the answer is to use a separate array—here I have used `@required`—to define the keys and the order that you want

Others have explained something very similar, so here I am using `grep` for a little variety. Instead of printing the keys of each sub-hash, I chose to print the elements of `@required` for which there exists a corresponding key

For the same reason I have used a `map` to create the pair of numeric values that need to be compared in the outer `sort` operation

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %my_hash=(
  gee1  => { CDS => 10, exon => 10, gene => 20, mRNA => 9, product => 10 },
  gee11 => { gene => "aa", locus => "abc", product => "ab", rRNA => 9 },
  gee2  => { CDS => "1aa", exon => "1aa", gene => "aa", mRNA => 9, product => "ab" },
  gee4  => { gene => "aa", locus => "abc", product => "ab", rRNA => 9 },
);

my @sorted_keys = sort {
  my ($aa, $bb) = map /(\d+)/, $a, $b;
  $aa <=> $bb;
} keys %my_hash;

my @required = qw/ gene mRNA rRNA CDS exon product locus /;

for my $key ( @sorted_keys ) {
  print "$key\n";
  for ( grep exists $my_hash{$key}{$_}, @required ) {
    print "    $_\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
gee1
    gene
    mRNA
    CDS
    exon
    product
gee2
    gene
    mRNA
    CDS
    exon
    product
gee4
    gene
    rRNA
    product
    locus
gee11
    gene
    rRNA
    product
    locus
```

---

**Update**

Those missing hash values are bothering me, and I should point out that you can produce them very simply by changing that last `print` statement to

```
print "    $_ = $my_hash{$key}{$_}\n"
```

The output is now

```
gee1
    gene = 20
    mRNA = 9
    CDS = 10
    exon = 10
    product = 10
gee2
    gene = aa
    mRNA = 9
    CDS = 1aa
    exon = 1aa
    product = ab
gee4
    gene = aa
    rRNA = 9
    product = ab
    locus = abc
gee11
    gene = aa
    rRNA = 9
    product = ab
    locus = abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing too much at once. Use two loops. The outer loop to sort your `%my_hash` of genes, and the inner loop to sort the items of your genes:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my %my_hash=(
    'gee1' =>  { 'gene' => '20', 'mRNA' => '9', 'CDS' => '10', 'exon' => '10', 'product' => '10', },
    'gee2'   =>  { 'gene' => 'aa', 'mRNA' => '9', 'CDS' => '1aa', 'exon' => '1aa', 'product' => 'ab', },
    'gee4'   =>  { 'gene' => 'aa', 'rRNA' => '9', 'product' => 'ab', 'locus' => 'abc' },
    'gee11'   =>  { 'gene' => 'aa', 'rRNA' => '9', 'product' => 'ab', 'locus' => 'abc' },
);

for my $gene ( sort {fc $a cmp fc $b} keys %my_hash ) {
    say $gene;
    my %types = %{$my_hash{$gene}};
    for my $type ( sort {fc $a cmp fc $b} keys %types ) {
        say "    $type: " . $my_hash{$gene}->{$type};
    }
}
```

Although I could have done just a straight sort on this dataset, I noticed that upper and lowercase keys existed. Using a pure `sort` command would sort in the *current collation locale* which may sort upper case letters before lowercase letters. Using the `fc` folds the case.

That is, I did this:

```
sort { fc $a cmp fc $b } @array;
```

Instead of just:

```
sort @array;
```

You can also look into using a [Schwartzian Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) which might be faster. If nothing else, you can use the Schwartzian Transformation to hold your data in sorted order in case you don't want to print it out immediately.